# How to best compare if the time part of a Date is between two LocalTime values with querydsl?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

QueryDSL Version 4.1.4 - upgrade not possible at the moment

How to best compare if the time part of a Date is between two LocalTime values with QueryDSL?

Declaration:

```java
private java.time.LocalTime.LocalTime beginTime; -> TIME in postgresql
private java.time.LocalTime.LocalTime endTime;  -> TIME in postgresql
private java.util.Date calltime; -> TIMESTAMP in postgresql
```

---

Expressions:

```java
TimeExpression<Date> calltimeTimePath = Expressions.asTime(qTicket.calltime);
TimePath<LocalTime> beginTimePath = qCallCenterTimeslot.beginTime;
TimePath<LocalTime> endTimePath = qCallCenterTimeslot.endTime;
```

---

Predicate:

```java
.where(calltimeTimePath.between(beginTimePath, endTimePath));
```

> Exception: Cannot resolve method 'between(com.querydsl.core.type.dsl.TimePath, com.querydsl.core.type.dsl.TimePath)'

Working example:

```
TimeExpression<LocalTime> testTimeExpression = Expressions.asTime(test);

.where(testTimeExpression.between(beginTimeExpression, endTimeExpression))
```

So maybe the best way would be to convert TimeExpression from Date to TimeExpression from LocalTime. But I've no clue how to achieve this?

---

In postgresql I can simply do:

```sql
SELECT t.calltime::TIME, *
FROM ticket t
     INNER JOIN call_center_timeslot c
             ON c.id=218
            AND t.calltime::TIME BETWEEN c.begin_time AND c.end_time;
```

Any thoughts how to best solve it?

Comment: Maybe I've found a solution:
TimeTemplate<LocalTime> calltimeTimeTemplate = Expressions.timeTemplate(LocalTime.class, "cast({0} AS {1})", qTicket.calltime, "TIME");